# Initializing a static field vs. returning a value in static property get?

Tags: c#, .net, static, properties, initialization

A) In the following code, will the method `DataTools.LoadSearchList()` only be called once, or every time the property is being accessed?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SearchWordList
{
    get
    {
        return DataTools.LoadSearchList();
    }
}
```

B) Is there any difference to this?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SearchWordList = DataTools.LoadSearchList();
```

Comment: Properties and fields behave entirely differently, even though they might appear similar from a coding point of view. A property is actually just a shortcut for a pair of get/set methods, and like any method, the body will be executed each time you call it..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your first example, LoadSearchList() will be called each time the property is accessed.

In the second, LoadSearchList() will only be called once (but it will be called whether you use it or not since it is now a field rather than a property).

A better option might be:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> _searchWordList;

public static IEnumerable<string> SearchWordList
{
    get 
    { 
        return _searchWordList ?? 
            ( _searchWordList = DataTools.LoadSearchList()); 
    }
}
```

Or if you're using .NET 4.0 and want something thread-safe you can use `Lazy<T>`, as Jon Skeet mentioned (I think the syntax should be correct, but don't hold me to it):

```
private static Lazy<IEnumerable<string>> _searchWordList =
    new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => DataTools.LoadSearchList());

public static IEnumerable<string> SearchWordList
{
    get { return _searchWordList.Value; }
}
```

Comment: Note that it *might* be called more than once, if there are multiple threads involved. Personally I'd prefer to use `Lazy<T>` from .NET 4, if that's an option. Then it's easy to adjust this sort of thing to make the second concurrent caller block, for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Updated with an example...hopefully I got the syntax right.

Comment: Looks good to me, although I *think* you could probably just do `new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(DataTools.LoadSearchList)` to use a method group conversion.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Will give you the best answer bonus for providing example code.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Lazy<T> - better than writing it out myself which is what i'd always done.

Answer (score 19):

In the first case the method will be called every time the property is accessed. When it's set as a field, it will be run exactly once - when the type it initialized - whether or not it's *ever* accessed.

If you want a lazily-initialized value, I'd recommend `Lazy<T>` from .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the property will call DataTools.LoadSearchList() every time access. The static field will only call the method once.